# Personal Online Money Saving

Tags: banking, online-banking, online-payment, online-tools, online-brokerage

I'm thirteen. I want to get some money for various online transactions. I do not want a full on bank account, nor can I get a joint checking account, because I don't to approach my dad about it. I have heard there are ways to get money by taking surveys and watching ads. I want a way to get the money from these actions, and somehow store online, and transfer to a game.

I listed the requirements for what I am looking for:

- An online way to hold money
- No actual account that will require dad
- Flexibility, preferably like an actual credit card
- Allow me to get money, and spend online

First Answer to meet requirements will be correct. Please, and Thank you.

Extra: Is mint or quicken something I should consider. I see a lot in the context of online and money management, but I fail to see the true accomplishments of such sites.

Comment: Mint and Quicken are tools to help manage your money. They can keep track of bank balances, track categories of expenses, and help you budget. Neither of them will hold money or allow you to spend it. If you're 13 and don't have a bank account, you don't really need Mint or Quicken, as you don't have any of this to keep track of. A simple [envelope budgeting](https://www.google.com/search?q=envelope+budgeting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) scheme would be much simpler if you wanted to start managing a personal budget.

Comment: In the US at least, you would need to file a tax return if you make enough money to qualify. Being a minor does not exempt you.  This scheme looks like a huge mess for you since it seems likely that at some point you're going to get kicked out of participating for being a minor without parental consent, lie about your age and then potentially have trouble with the IRS, or some unknown other horror.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely check the _envelope budgeting scheme_, and certainly take tax return in consideration.

Comment: Honestly, PayPal is what you want. Most of the paid-to-do sites out there pay their people using PayPal. And a lot of game sites allow you to use PayPal as a payment. BUT requires Dad :(

Comment: Maybe you should concentrate on gowing well in school so you can get a well paid job instead of blowing your time on surveys and games. I think you need to start taking your dad's advice and stop trying to do things behind his back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for are sites that offer pre-paid debit cards as rewards. A number of survey/get-paid-to sites do offer these as a potential reward; they are more irritating than having the money in a bank account or paypal balance, as they expire if not used within some amount of time, and generally come with restrictions on what you can use them on (they work *like* credit cards, but the site providing the card can reject your request if it doesn't like the site you're trying to pay.). Plus, you can only use a single debit card per purchase, so if you have two $20 prepaid cards, you can't use them both to make a $40 dollar purchase. Still, this does satisfy your requirements, assuming the game you want to transfer to and the provider of the prepaid card you're being rewarded with are willing to work together.

You can use [SurveyPolice](http://www.surveypolice.com/pick-a-perk) to search for sites that offer the type of reward you want - filtering by offered reward type is an option under their "pick-a-perk" page.

Though it's likely many of those sites also require you to be at least 18 as well, as that's a pretty common restriction - you'll have to verify that part yourself. For that matter, you would want to check age restrictions on the sites those sites partner with to offer prepaid cards, as well.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question. It doesn't say Pre-paid debit cards, but it does say stuff like Walmart Gift Card. I'm assuming the one I want is the Visa Pre-Paid Card?

Comment: @Magic9995 Yes, Visa. Visa is a company that, among other things, is responsible for the operation of a significant percentage of all debit cards, including prepaid ones.

Comment: What stupid advice to give a 13 year old.